# Swing: JLabels in JPanel one-on-line with width = content width

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JPanel` in which I want to add several `JLabel`s the following way:

- only single `JLabel` is placed on one line (next `JLabel` is placed below the previous one)
- each `JLabel` takes only the mininal possible width (i.e. the width of it's content); I need this because I have mouse click listeners on `JLabel`s and I don't want them to be trigerred when user clicks somewhere near `JLabel`.

I tried to do it like this:

```
myPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(myPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
myPanel.add(new JLabel("label1"));
myPanel.add(new JLabel("label2"));
```

But with such implementation I can click not only on `JLabel` itself (i.e. it's text) but somewhere near it and mouse listener will still be triggered.

What am I doint wrong?

Comment: What if you place each JLabel into its own JPanel such as `myPanel.add(new JPanel() {{ add(new JLabel("label1")); }});`

Comment: But for better help, please create and post your [mcve].

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I wouldn't have expected **you** to recommend this plague that is sometimes referred to as "double-brace-initialization". The [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) offers clean way of achieving this goal.

Comment: @Marco13: I normally don't use it, but it fits nicely within a comment. :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I see. But when there's not enough space, then that's the way it is. *(TODO: Insert some geeky reference to Fermat's last theorem here)* ;-) . So @coolguy : You should **not** use this `{{ double-brace }}` thingy.

Comment: In any case, the recommendation to post a [MCVE] still stands. The behavior that you are looking for **should** be the default behavior. If you observe a different behavior, then this must be caused by other parts of the code....

Comment: A BoxLayout respects the maximum size of a component. The preferredSize and maximumSize of a label are the same so events for the label are only generated if you click on the label. To test this: 1) make your label opaque 2) set the background color of the label so you can see the true size of the label and see if you are actually clicking on the label or the panel.

Comment: A BoxLayout respects the maximum size of a component. The preferredSize and maximumSize of a label are the same so events for the label are only generated if you click on the label. To test this: 1) make your label opaque 2) set the background color of the label so you can see the true size of the label and see if you are actually clicking on the label or the panel. If you are clicking on the panel, then you must be adding the MouseLIstener to the panel as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I need this because I have mouse click listeners on JLabels

Another approach is to use a JButton so you don't need to add custom event processing.

Then you can use:

```
button.setBorderPainted( false );
button.setContentAreaFilled( false );
button.setOpaque( false );
```

and the button will look like a label. But then you just add an ActionListener to the button for normal event processing.